# Can we use helper in controller laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cakephp, helper

I am new in **laravel** and I have good experience in **Cakephp**. In Cakephp we use helper for views only But I have seen my exiting code in laravel, We use helpers in controller also. Is it fine to use helper in controller or not?

If yes then Please let me know, What is the disadvantage or advantage of using helpers in controllers?

Please suggest me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about global [Laravel helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers), then yes, you can use them everywhere in your app (controllers, models, view, middleware, `routes.php` etc), because these are global helpers.

You can also define your own helpers which will also be available globally.